# Background Image workaround in a HTML/CSS Hex

Tags: html, css, background, hex

### What I am looking for ?

I am looking to use a image background for each distinct hexagon, in side of a hexagon grid made with HTML and CSS.

### What I have tried before ?

I had made hex's before, using photoshop and a messy SASS loop to generate the absolute cells for the grid itself, well, it made responsiveness hard to achieve.

### Why I don't want to use the same grid ?

- Takes time to create new hex cells, with `photoshop` and `SVG`,
- Hard to keep it responsive either smooth,
- It seemed to be a messy solution,

### What I have done so far ?

Today I am looking forward to use following hex:

**Codepen Example,**
https://codepen.io/elbarto84/pen/wrcob/

**CSS**

```
@import "compass/css3";

$hex-size: 6em; // Only change size here. Best used with sizes from 5em - 10em.

/* ----------------------------------------- */
.container {
  width: 1000px; 
  line-height: 1.3;
}
ol.even {
  position: relative;
  left: ($hex-size / 1.1);
}
ol.odd {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -6.5%;
  margin-bottom: -6.5%;
}
.hex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: $hex-size; height: ($hex-size * 1.7);
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: ($hex-size / 1.30);
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.hex:before, .hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.hex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hex:hover {
  background: #F58787;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <ol class="even">
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
  </ol>  
  <ol class="odd">
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="even">
    <li class='hex'></li>
    <li class='hex'></li>
  </ol>  
</div>
```

- Tried `background-attachment`, on `.hex`, `.hex:after`, `.hex:before`;
- Tried a distinct absolute `<div>` that had be used for the bg;

### Any idea ?

Is there any trick either idea about how it could be achieved ?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by: "I need to use image backgrounds for a hex grid I want to implement.".

Comment: Do you want each hex to have its own distinct backgrounds or one background behind all of them

Comment: I am looking to use a image background for each distinct hexagon

Comment: Could you try reaching each of your elements by using something like : document.getElementById('add_an_id_here').nextSibling ? and then add a specific background for each

Comment: @DevMoutarde Thank you for your input, it's something i could try. I'll update, doesn't seem there will be too many possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Added a small class named 'test'

```
<li class='hex test'></li>
```

Added a link to the background

```
.hex.test {
  background-image: url("http://www.shunvmall.com/data/out/193/47864981-random-image.gif");
}
```

And it worked.

Comment: this ? http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/03/05/0014/1091/951363/63/50f47fdbc9.jpg, i was looking for something like this http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2016/11/15/0014/1091/951363/63/11fb03a74a.jpg

Comment: Just position the image using background-position property.